# Display current logged in user's avatar outside of the loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, avatar

I use the famous User Photo plugin for my Wordpress site. I want to display the current logged in user's avatar outside the loop. How is this possible?

The current code I use to display the author avatar inside the loop is:

```
<?php userphoto_the_author_thumbnail('', '', array(width => '40', height => '40')); ?>
```

Google did not give me much to go on. One person referred to this code:

```
global $authordata;
$authordata=get_userdata(get_query_var( 'author' ));
userphoto_the_author_thumbnail();
```

But it did not work. What is the solution?

Comment: And what loop are you referring to?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use userphoto_thumbnail() and pass the user ID explicitly.

Usage:

```
userphoto_thumbnail($user, $before = '', $after = '', $attributes = array(), $default_src = '')
```

Comment: This actually worked! However, how do I get the width/height in there? If you look at my original code, you will see: **array(width => '40', height => '40'**

Comment: Replace `$attributes = array()` with `array(width => '40', height => '40')`

Comment: Excellent, works perfectly. Thank you for saving me further hours of confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code.

It will select the current logged-in user's email and then display the avatar.

```
<?php
    wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_email = $current_user->user_email;
?>
<?php echo get_avatar( '$current_user_email', 40 ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try one of thes two.

```
userphoto($user, $before = '', $after = '', $attributes = array(), $default_src = '')
```

or

```
userphoto_thumbnail($user, $before = '', $after = '', $attributes = array(), $default_src = '')
```

Both function work same as `userphoto_the_author_thumbnail`

thanks

Comment: How do I get the width/height in there? If you look at my original code, you will see: **array(width => '40', height => '40'**

Comment: `$attributes` is for different parameter,you can assign `width,height,style` different in it. for eg. $attributes = `aeeat('width'=>40,'height'=>40,'style'=>'border:0')`.